# Magento 2: composer update from 2.3.0 to 2.3.5-p1 fails with missing ext-mcrypt

Tags: magento2, upgrade, composer

I have a magento 2.3.0 install (just upgraded from 2.2.7) running on php 7.2 (PHP 7.2.31-1+0~20200514.41+debian9~1.gbpe2a56b).

Now I wanted to upgrade to 2.3.5-p1 using composer:

```
composer require magento/product-community-edition=2.3.5-p1
```

But it fails with this error message:

```
  Problem 1
    - magento/framework 101.0.9 requires ext-mcrypt * -> the requested PHP extension mcrypt is missing from your system.
    - magento/framework 101.0.8 requires ext-mcrypt * -> the requested PHP extension mcrypt is missing from your system.
    - magento/framework 101.0.7 requires ext-mcrypt * -> the requested PHP extension mcrypt is missing from your system.
    - magento/framework 101.0.6 requires ext-mcrypt * -> the requested PHP extension mcrypt is missing from your system.
    - magento/framework 101.0.5 requires ext-mcrypt * -> the requested PHP extension mcrypt is missing from your system.
    - magento/framework 101.0.4 requires ext-mcrypt * -> the requested PHP extension mcrypt is missing from your system.
    - magento/framework 101.0.3 requires ext-mcrypt * -> the requested PHP extension mcrypt is missing from your system.
    - magento/framework 101.0.2 requires ext-mcrypt * -> the requested PHP extension mcrypt is missing from your system.
    - magento/framework 101.0.1 requires ext-mcrypt * -> the requested PHP extension mcrypt is missing from your system.
    - magento/framework 101.0.0 requires ext-mcrypt * -> the requested PHP extension mcrypt is missing from your system.
    - magento/framework 100.1.9 requires ext-mcrypt * -> the requested PHP extension mcrypt is missing from your system.
    - magento/framework 100.1.8 requires ext-mcrypt * -> the requested PHP extension mcrypt is missing from your system.
    - magento/framework 100.1.7 requires ext-mcrypt * -> the requested PHP extension mcrypt is missing from your system.
    - magento/framework 100.1.6 requires ext-mcrypt * -> the requested PHP extension mcrypt is missing from your system.
    - magento/framework 100.1.5 requires ext-mcrypt * -> the requested PHP extension mcrypt is missing from your system.
    - magento/framework 100.1.4 requires ext-mcrypt * -> the requested PHP extension mcrypt is missing from your system.
    - magento/framework 100.1.3 requires ext-mcrypt * -> the requested PHP extension mcrypt is missing from your system.
    - magento/framework 100.1.2 requires ext-mcrypt * -> the requested PHP extension mcrypt is missing from your system.
    - magento/framework 100.1.18 requires ext-mcrypt * -> the requested PHP extension mcrypt is missing from your system.
    - magento/framework 100.1.17 requires ext-mcrypt * -> the requested PHP extension mcrypt is missing from your system.
    - magento/framework 100.1.16 requires ext-mcrypt * -> the requested PHP extension mcrypt is missing from your system.
    - magento/framework 100.1.15 requires ext-mcrypt * -> the requested PHP extension mcrypt is missing from your system.
    - magento/framework 100.1.14 requires ext-mcrypt * -> the requested PHP extension mcrypt is missing from your system.
    - magento/framework 100.1.13 requires ext-mcrypt * -> the requested PHP extension mcrypt is missing from your system.
    - magento/framework 100.1.12 requires ext-mcrypt * -> the requested PHP extension mcrypt is missing from your system.
    - magento/framework 100.1.11 requires ext-mcrypt * -> the requested PHP extension mcrypt is missing from your system.
    - magento/framework 100.1.10 requires ext-mcrypt * -> the requested PHP extension mcrypt is missing from your system.
    - magento/framework 100.1.1 requires ext-mcrypt * -> the requested PHP extension mcrypt is missing from your system.
    - magento/framework 100.1.0 requires ext-mcrypt * -> the requested PHP extension mcrypt is missing from your system.
    - magento/framework 100.1.0 requires php ~5.6.0|7.0.2|~7.0.6 -> your PHP version (7.2.31) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - magento/framework 100.1.1 requires php ~5.6.0|7.0.2|~7.0.6 -> your PHP version (7.2.31) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - magento/framework 100.1.2 requires php ~5.6.5|7.0.2|7.0.4|~7.0.6 -> your PHP version (7.2.31) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - magento/framework 100.1.3 requires php ~5.6.5|7.0.2|7.0.4|~7.0.6 -> your PHP version (7.2.31) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - magento/framework 100.1.4 requires php ~5.6.5|7.0.2|7.0.4|~7.0.6 -> your PHP version (7.2.31) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - magento/framework 100.1.5 requires php ~5.6.5|7.0.2|7.0.4|~7.0.6 -> your PHP version (7.2.31) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - magento/framework 100.1.6 requires php ~5.6.5|7.0.2|7.0.4|~7.0.6 -> your PHP version (7.2.31) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - magento/framework 100.1.7 requires php ~5.6.5|7.0.2|7.0.4|~7.0.6 -> your PHP version (7.2.31) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - magento/framework 100.1.8 requires php ~5.6.5|7.0.2|7.0.4|~7.0.6 -> your PHP version (7.2.31) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - magento/framework 100.1.9 requires php ~5.6.5|7.0.2|7.0.4|~7.0.6 -> your PHP version (7.2.31) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - magento/framework 101.0.0 requires php 7.0.2|7.0.4|~7.0.6|~7.1.0 -> your PHP version (7.2.31) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - magento/framework 101.0.1 requires php 7.0.2|7.0.4|~7.0.6|~7.1.0 -> your PHP version (7.2.31) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - magento/framework 100.1.10 requires php ~5.6.5|7.0.2|7.0.4|~7.0.6 -> your PHP version (7.2.31) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - magento/framework 100.1.11 requires php ~5.6.5|7.0.2|7.0.4|~7.0.6 -> your PHP version (7.2.31) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - magento/framework 101.0.2 requires php 7.0.2|7.0.4|~7.0.6|~7.1.0 -> your PHP version (7.2.31) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - magento/framework 100.1.12 requires php ~5.6.5|7.0.2|7.0.4|~7.0.6 -> your PHP version (7.2.31) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - magento/framework 101.0.3 requires php 7.0.2|7.0.4|~7.0.6|~7.1.0 -> your PHP version (7.2.31) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - magento/framework 100.1.13 requires php ~5.6.5|7.0.2|7.0.4|~7.0.6 -> your PHP version (7.2.31) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - magento/framework 101.0.4 requires php 7.0.2|7.0.4|~7.0.6|~7.1.0 -> your PHP version (7.2.31) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - magento/framework 101.0.5 requires php ~7.0.13|~7.1.0 -> your PHP version (7.2.31) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - magento/framework 100.1.14 requires php ~5.6.5|7.0.2|7.0.4|~7.0.6 -> your PHP version (7.2.31) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - magento/framework 100.1.15 requires php ~5.6.5|7.0.2|7.0.4|~7.0.6 -> your PHP version (7.2.31) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - magento/framework 101.0.6 requires php ~7.0.13|~7.1.0 -> your PHP version (7.2.31) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - magento/framework 100.1.16 requires php ~5.6.5|7.0.2|7.0.4|~7.0.6|~7.1.0 -> your PHP version (7.2.31) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - magento/framework 101.0.7 requires php ~7.0.13|~7.1.0 -> your PHP version (7.2.31) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - magento/framework 100.1.17 requires php ~5.6.5|7.0.2|7.0.4|~7.0.6|~7.1.0 -> your PHP version (7.2.31) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - magento/framework 101.0.8 requires php ~7.0.13|~7.1.0 -> your PHP version (7.2.31) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - magento/framework 100.1.18 requires php ~5.6.5|7.0.2|7.0.4|~7.0.6|~7.1.0 -> your PHP version (7.2.31) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - magento/framework 101.0.9 requires php ~7.0.13|~7.1.0 -> your PHP version (7.2.31) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - Conclusion: remove fooman/printorderpdf-m2 3.1.7
    - Conclusion: don't install fooman/printorderpdf-m2 3.1.7
    - Conclusion: don't install magento/framework 102.0.4-p2
    - Conclusion: don't install magento/product-community-edition 2.3.5-p1
    - magento/framework 101.0.11 requires zendframework/zend-stdlib ^2.7.7 -> satisfiable by zendframework/zend-stdlib[2.7.7], laminas/laminas-stdlib[2.7.7].
    - magento/framework 102.0.2-p2 requires zendframework/zend-stdlib ^2.7.7 -> satisfiable by zendframework/zend-stdlib[2.7.7], laminas/laminas-stdlib[2.7.7].
    - magento/framework 101.0.10 requires zendframework/zend-stdlib ^2.7.7 -> satisfiable by zendframework/zend-stdlib[2.7.7], laminas/laminas-stdlib[2.7.7].
    - magento/framework 102.0.2 requires zendframework/zend-stdlib ^2.7.7 -> satisfiable by zendframework/zend-stdlib[2.7.7], laminas/laminas-stdlib[2.7.7].
    - magento/framework 102.0.1 requires zendframework/zend-stdlib ^2.7.7 -> satisfiable by zendframework/zend-stdlib[2.7.7], laminas/laminas-stdlib[2.7.7].
    - magento/framework 102.0.0 requires zendframework/zend-stdlib ^2.7.7 -> satisfiable by zendframework/zend-stdlib[2.7.7], laminas/laminas-stdlib[2.7.7].
    - magento/framework 102.0.0 requires zendframework/zend-stdlib ^2.7.7 -> satisfiable by zendframework/zend-stdlib[2.7.7], laminas/laminas-stdlib[2.7.7].
    - magento/framework 101.0.10 requires zendframework/zend-stdlib ^2.7.7 -> satisfiable by zendframework/zend-stdlib[2.7.7], laminas/laminas-stdlib[2.7.7].
    - magento/framework 101.0.11 requires zendframework/zend-stdlib ^2.7.7 -> satisfiable by zendframework/zend-stdlib[2.7.7], laminas/laminas-stdlib[2.7.7].
    - magento/framework 102.0.0 requires zendframework/zend-stdlib ^2.7.7 -> satisfiable by zendframework/zend-stdlib[2.7.7], laminas/laminas-stdlib[2.7.7].
    - magento/framework 102.0.1 requires zendframework/zend-stdlib ^2.7.7 -> satisfiable by zendframework/zend-stdlib[2.7.7], laminas/laminas-stdlib[2.7.7].
    - magento/framework 102.0.2 requires zendframework/zend-stdlib ^2.7.7 -> satisfiable by zendframework/zend-stdlib[2.7.7], laminas/laminas-stdlib[2.7.7].
    - magento/framework 102.0.2-p2 requires zendframework/zend-stdlib ^2.7.7 -> satisfiable by zendframework/zend-stdlib[2.7.7], laminas/laminas-stdlib[2.7.7].
    - Can only install one of: laminas/laminas-stdlib[3.2.1, 2.7.7].
    - don't install zendframework/zend-stdlib 2.7.7|don't install laminas/laminas-stdlib 3.2.1
    - don't install laminas/laminas-stdlib 3.2.1|remove zendframework/zend-stdlib 2.7.7
    - magento/product-community-edition 2.3.5-p1 requires laminas/laminas-stdlib ^3.2.1 -> satisfiable by laminas/laminas-stdlib[3.2.1].
    - Installation request for fooman/printorderpdf-m2 3.1.7 -> satisfiable by fooman/printorderpdf-m2[3.1.7].
    - Installation request for magento/product-community-edition 2.3.5-p1 -> satisfiable by magento/product-community-edition[2.3.5-p1].
    - fooman/printorderpdf-m2 3.1.7 requires magento/framework 100.1.0 - 100.1.18 | 101.0.0 - 101.0.11 | >=102.0.0 <102.0.5 -> satisfiable by magento/framework[102.0.0, 100.1.0, 100.1.1, 100.1.10, 100.1.11, 100.1.12, 100.1.13, 100.1.14, 100.1.15, 100.1.16, 100.1.17, 100.1.18, 100.1.2, 100.1.3, 100.1.4, 100.1.5, 100.1.6, 100.1.7, 100.1.8, 100.1.9, 101.0.0, 101.0.1, 101.0.10, 101.0.11, 101.0.2, 101.0.3, 101.0.4, 101.0.5, 101.0.6, 101.0.7, 101.0.8, 101.0.9, 102.0.1, 102.0.2, 102.0.2-p2, 102.0.3, 102.0.3-p1, 102.0.4, 102.0.4-p2].
    - Can only install one of: magento/framework[102.0.3-p1, 102.0.5].
    - Can only install one of: magento/framework[102.0.4, 102.0.5].
    - Can only install one of: magento/framework[102.0.3, 102.0.5].
    - Can only install one of: magento/framework[102.0.5, 102.0.3].
    - Can only install one of: magento/framework[102.0.5, 102.0.3-p1].
    - Can only install one of: magento/framework[102.0.5, 102.0.4].
    - Can only install one of: magento/framework[102.0.5, 102.0.4-p2].
    - magento/product-community-edition 2.3.5-p1 requires magento/framework 102.0.5 -> satisfiable by magento/framework[102.0.5].
    - Conclusion: don't install magento/framework 102.0.5|keep magento/framework 102.0.0|install magento/framework 101.0.10|install magento/framework 101.0.11|install magento/framework 102.0.0|install magento/framework 102.0.1|install magento/framework 102.0.2|install magento/framework 102.0.2-p2|install magento/framework 101.0.11|install magento/framework 102.0.2-p2|install magento/framework 101.0.10|install magento/framework 102.0.2|install magento/framework 102.0.1|install magento/framework 102.0.0

  To enable extensions, verify that they are enabled in your .ini files:
    - /etc/php/7.2/cli/php.ini
    - /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/10-mysqlnd.ini
    - /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/10-opcache.ini
    - /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/10-pdo.ini
    - /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/15-xml.ini
    - /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-bcmath.ini
    - /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-calendar.ini
    - /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-ctype.ini
    - /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-curl.ini
    - /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-dom.ini
    - /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-exif.ini
    - /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-fileinfo.ini
    - /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-ftp.ini
    - /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-gd.ini
    - /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-gettext.ini
    - /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-iconv.ini
    - /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-imagick.ini
    - /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-intl.ini
    - /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-json.ini
    - /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-mbstring.ini
    - /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-mysqli.ini
    - /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-pdo_mysql.ini
    - /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-phar.ini
    - /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-posix.ini
    - /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-readline.ini
    - /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-shmop.ini
    - /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-simplexml.ini
    - /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-soap.ini
    - /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-sockets.ini
    - /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-ssh2.ini
    - /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-sysvmsg.ini
    - /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-sysvsem.ini
    - /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-sysvshm.ini
    - /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-tokenizer.ini
    - /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-wddx.ini
    - /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-xmlreader.ini
    - /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-xmlwriter.ini
    - /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-xsl.ini
    - /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-zip.ini
    - /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/25-mailparse.ini
  You can also run `php --ini` inside terminal to see which files are used by PHP in CLI mode.
```

My understanding is that mcrypt is deprecated/obsolete for some time. So why does magento/composer somewhow require it now?

Weird thing: I have another magento 2.3.5 installation (from scratch, no upgrade from older version) which runs just fine with this setup.

So I tried this:

```
composer require magento/product-community-edition=2.3.5-p1 --ignore-platform-reqs
```

This fails with these errors:

```
  Problem 1
    - Installation request for webonyx/graphql-php (locked at v0.12.6) -> satisfiable by webonyx/graphql-php[v0.12.6].
    - magento/product-community-edition 2.3.5-p1 requires webonyx/graphql-php ^0.13.8 -> satisfiable by webonyx/graphql-php[v0.13.8].
    - magento/product-community-edition 2.3.5-p1 requires webonyx/graphql-php ^0.13.8 -> satisfiable by webonyx/graphql-php[v0.13.8].
    - Conclusion: don't install webonyx/graphql-php v0.13.8
    - Installation request for magento/product-community-edition 2.3.5-p1 -> satisfiable by magento/product-community-edition[2.3.5-p1].
```

I'm kinda lost here.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, it looks like I was reading the error messages wrong. Although I don't quite know why composer would tell me mcrypt was missing.

```
Conclusion: remove fooman/printorderpdf-m2 3.1.7
```

I removed this module and the install went smoothly.